# Grafana shows promethese couter data decrease and increases

Tags: prometheus, grafana, prometheus-node-exporter

[image: here is graph plotted by Grafana. Its taking pyrromethene couter data. But the counter data is fluctuating between 10 and 15.]

here is graph plotted by Grafana. Its taking pyrromethene couter data. But the counter data is fluctuating between 10 and 15.

So my question is, counter data never decreases in Prometheus but still in graph my counter is increasing and decreasing which is giving wrong impression of metric. Can anyone tell why its happening.

UPDATE:[image].
i am using a raw (metric name) query, to fetch the data from Prometheus.

Note: also i want to highlight that i am using Prometheus on my pods of K8s. is that is causing the issue?

Comment: Can you post the query you're using ? Are you using a function like rate or increase ? Or is it raw values ?

Comment: Hi @MarcABOUCHACRA, i have just updated the post. Yes,  i am using a raw query.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I see the same with something as simple as `http_requests_total`